# Element dragging in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring

I want to implement item dragging. I'm using react. I came up with two ways on doing this: changing element `style` attribute (so i need to store variable in state) or create independent variables and change directly from JS. What is preferred and more performant way? It seems like using both of this ways do not affect badly on code style.

Comment: maybe this lib can help you: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd

Comment: Without seeing the code it's hard to say which would be more performant, however generally in react it's best to avoid modifying elements directly, so your first option sounds preferable (Though again, we really need more detail to give a good answer to this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using setState is ok and almost do not have performance loss.